# Other than modifying the method name, how do you control the run sequence of methods within a unit test in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I would like to ensure test methods within unit test are run in a particular sequence. There's not a dependency on a previous method. The tests are isolated. The sequence is obviously alphabetic based on method name. Is there a way to control run order through an attribute?

Comment: Why? If they are isolated, the order doesn't matter, if they aren't isolated but depend on a specific order: make them isolated

Comment: If anything I would look for an automatic randomizer so that tests are always run in a different order to ensure isolation is true. If instead you're looking for how to run a subset of tests across the entire suite, or a way to always run something like smaller/faster tests first, then that's borderline a different question.

Comment: The question relates to organization and management of tests and how they're run and reviewed. While I appreciate your arguments, I do have my reasons. Please answer the question as asked if possible.